# How to make gradle bypass test tasks for projects where java classes (inputs) have not changed

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a multi project (> 20) git repository. When I execute a gradle build, I only want the test tasks in the projects where java classes (inputs) have changed since the last time I built to execute. I tried specifying .../build/classes/main as inputs and .../build/classes/test as output for the test task thinking gradle would detect that these did not change between builds and not execute the test task, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that should be the default behavior of Gradle. Have you tried the `--info` or `--debug` flags to try and see why Gradle thinks it needs to execute the tests?

Unless the issue is the multi-project build itself. If you have A & B, and B depends on A, and you change A, then the tests of B are run even though B did not change. However, since a dependency of B changed, it would likely be correct for its tests to execute.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes I found --info after posting this and it did help. Turns out there's a manifest.mf file that get rebuilt every build (only thing that changes in it is the datetime stamp) and this causes a domino effect of rebuilding java classes which in turn causes all tests to re run. Working on preventing the manifest.mf file from being recreated each build. Thanks for you answer!

Comment: An up vote and a green checkmark would be thanks enough.